# Cannot access mysql database after migrating from Homestead to Sail

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am trying to migrate a Laravel 8 project from Homestead to Sail. Sail seems to be set up correctly since I can get to my project's website locally. But I can't get into mysql to look around in the database:

```
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ sail mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myproject'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried restarting Docker, and restarting my terminal and running `sail build --no-cache && sail up` to no avail.

Here is the relevant portion of my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myproject
DB_USERNAME=myproject
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And here is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

EDIT:
When I change my .env to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myproject
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Then the error is

```
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ sail mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'myproject'
```

Comment: The ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myproject'@'localhost' (using password: YES) implies you are hitting the MySql server, only the username or password is incorrect

Comment: is there any other apache/mysql service runing on the pc? that can cause conflicts, in that case you should stop them.

Comment: Try runing the command `php artisan sail:install`, when doing it watch your `/.env` file, the `DB_` section will change to the default values. After that retray with `sail up`.

Comment: No other apache/mysql services running to my knowledge

Comment: When I run `php artisan sail:install` all that gets set is `DB_PASSWORD=password`. `DB_USERNAME` remains unchanged.

Comment: And the error message stays the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Just tried to connect to a fresh laravel 9 app and I think you only need to change a few lines in order to connect to Sail's Mysql:

#### .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myproject 
DB_USERNAME=sail # <-- "sail" as default user name
DB_PASSWORD=password # <-- "password" as default password
```

This is needed because **"mysql"** is the name of the instance of the database section in the docker container that **sail uses** to interact with the database.

All other settings still the same.

Then as you do before `sail build --no-cache && sail up`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the results of your suggested edit.

Comment: I set `DB_HOST=host.docker.internal` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `FORWARD_DB_PORT` key in my `.env` file and running `sail up` again seemed to work for me!

```
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3307
```

**When you're connecting to the database, make sure to use the above specified port!**